# Unable to set range header for HttpWebRequest in windows 8 store application

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am unable to set range header for HttpWebRequest in windows 8 store application, if I try to set the range in different ways as in below sample code I encounter the following exception,
The 'Range' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.Parameter name: name.

What are my alternatives to set the range header with following conditions.
1.Immediate response callback  by setting  AllowReadStreamBuffering = false; so that I continuously write it to a file and get download progress.

Code is:

```
WebHeaderCollection headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
headers[HttpRequestHeader.Range] = "bytes=" + CurrentBufferPointer + "-"; 

HttpWebRequest DownLoadClient = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.FileUri);
DownLoadClient.Method = "GET";
DownLoadClient.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
```

// setting either of two below ways throws an exception

```
DownLoadClient.Headers = headers;   
Or 
DownLoadClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Range] = "bytes=" + CurrentBufferPointer +  "-";

DownLoadClient.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), DownLoadClient);
```

When I am setting  DownLoadClient.Headers = headers; this exception will come :

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, this.FileUri);
request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(0, 1024); //if range is of "bytes=0-1024";
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: but with HTTPclient one cannot have chunk downloads and resume later from where it left off...